# How to consume,response with the JSON POST data in express application

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, mongodb, express

I am using NodeJS and MongoDB.I have a simple app.You type your data to the textarea,when click submit,it creates a new object in a database.Then if you wanna check certain information in your database,you can type to input an id.It will search in the database for the object with the same id and then it will show you the information on the next page.It works nicely.But what i also need,is that if you will send the JSON POST request to my server,let's say,through POSTMAN,i want it to be displayed not as HTML,but as a JSON object.I guess i need to right a middleware that will check the request first,and if it should be html,it will keep running the code that renders an HTML,and if there is JSON request,then it will do another thing.

That's the code that finds the right object by it's id to show on the webpage:

```
app.post("/insertedids", function(req,res){
var inputid = req.body.emails;
db.collection('emails').find({"_id": ObjectId(inputid)}).toArray(function(err, foundObject){
  if(err){
        console.log(err)
    } else {
         res.render("insertedids",{emailslist: foundObject[0].emails});

    };
});
```

});

And this is the code on the page where it shows the data:

```
<% include partials/header %>
 <div class="centeredlist">
   <h1>Emails on this ID </h1>
   <ul>
    <% emailslist.forEach(function(email){ %>
       <li><%=email%></li><br/>
 <% });%>
   </ul>
 </div>
<% include partials/footer %>
```

So i need that if there is a Json request,it will respond by showing a json objects,not an li's.
P.s inpuid that's the name of my input.
P.s.s i am sorry if i made grammar mistakes :D

Comment: You are thinking on the right track. You can do two things from here. The cleaner way is to separate your endpoints for returning a template and json. Or you can send a key alongside your inputid and based on that return either res.render or res.json. I will recommend way number one.

Comment: A variation on the second approach suggested by @amanpurohit is to use `res.format`, http://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#res.format, which determines the response format based on the `Accept` header.

Comment: @skirtle thanks for suggesting a better approach.